# G apps script sheet is asking repeatedly asking for authorization although granted it several times (time-driven trigger)

Tags: triggers, authorization, spreadsheet

From 6/21/18 1:59 AM CET on one of the google spreadsheets with scripts in the background is asking me repeatedly for authorization respectively is sending the 'Summary of failures for Google Apps Script' email with the following content.

Start   Function    Error Message   Trigger End
6/21/18 3:54 AM ScanGmail   Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  6/21/18 3:54 AM

I've used 'function auth() {}' several times now to grant authorization again (seems like I have to do it every time I log out or the computer turned into sleep mode).

I've also the authorization script implemented but no email to grant the authorization gets sent, only the apps script error notification.

```
var addonTitle = 'PRE_Inv_Conf';
var props = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
var authInfo = ScriptApp.getAuthorizationInfo(ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL);

// Check if the actions of the trigger requires authorization that has not
// been granted yet; if so, warn the user via email. This check is required
// when using triggers with add-ons to maintain functional triggers.
if (authInfo.getAuthorizationStatus() ==
   ScriptApp.AuthorizationStatus.REQUIRED) {
// Re-authorization is required. In this case, the user needs to be alerted
// that they need to re-authorize; the normal trigger action is not
// conducted, since it requires authorization first. Send at most one
// "Authorization Required" email per day to avoid spamming users.
var lastAuthEmailDate = props.getProperty('lastAuthEmailDate');
var today = new Date().toDateString();
if (lastAuthEmailDate != today) {
  if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) {
    var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('AuthorizationEmail');
    html.url = authInfo.getAuthorizationUrl();
    html.addonTitle = addonTitle;
    var message = html.evaluate();
    MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(),
                       'Authorization Required',
                       message.getContent(), {
                         name: addonTitle,
                         htmlBody: message.getContent()
                       }
                      );
  }
   props.setProperty('lastAuthEmailDate', today);
 }
} else {
```

Was something changed on Google side at 6/21/18 1:59 AM CET or what is going wrong and is there a way to avoid that behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is a Google bug because there was nothing changed from my side on the affected spreadsheet or related google account. Not sure if it appeared because I'm running more than one Google account but here is my solution.

1. Disconnect from all accounts
2. Close the used browser
3. open the browser again
4. open an incognito window
5. login to the account that owns the spreadsheet (or was used to set the triggers)
6. remove all triggers via script editor-> Edit -> Current projet's triggers
7. save this none-selection of triggers
8. re-open the trigger setup (Edit -> Current projet's triggers)
9. set all triggers once again along with granting the authorization once again

So far it seems that this workaround fixed the Google bug. The spreadsheet respectively the scripts in the background are now running like expected/ like they did before 06/21/18 1:59 AM CET